# Apply empty row between two blocks of different dates

Tags: php, wordpress, date, themes

I've been trying to work out something in my Wordpress Theme (Football Club, from Themeboy).

For example, on this page: [Example Link](http://www.ritaberlaar.be/u15-reeks-t-niv-21-volledige-kalender-20172018/)

You see a list of a whole bunch of matches, in blocks of 4 per play date.

```
03/09/2017  K. Lierse SK D      10:00   Heikant Berlaar
03/09/2017  K. FC Pulle B       10:00   K. RAC. Emblem B
03/09/2017  K. Bevel FC A       10:00   K. Ramsel FC 
03/09/2017  SK Rita Berlaar A   10:00   Kessel United
10/09/2017  K. FC Pulle B       10:00   SK Rita Berlaar A 
10/09/2017  Kessel United       11:00   K. Bevel FC A
10/09/2017  K. RAC. Emblem B    11:15   Heikant Berlaar
10/09/2017  K. Ramsel FC        11:30   K. Lierse SK D K
17/09/2017  SK Rita Berlaar A   10:00   K. RAC. Emblem B
17/09/2017  Heikant Berlaar     10:00   K. Ramsel FC 
17/09/2017  K. Bevel FC A       10:00   K. FC Pulle B
17/09/2017  K. Lierse SK D      11:45   Kessel United
```

What I would like to do is apply an empty row, every time the play date changes, so it looks like this.

```
03/09/2017  K. Lierse SK D      10:00   Heikant Berlaar
03/09/2017  K. FC Pulle B       10:00   K. RAC. Emblem B
03/09/2017  K. Bevel FC A       10:00   K. Ramsel FC 
03/09/2017  SK Rita Berlaar A   10:00   Kessel United
(Empty row)
10/09/2017  K. FC Pulle B       10:00   SK Rita Berlaar A 
10/09/2017  Kessel United       11:00   K. Bevel FC A
10/09/2017  K. RAC. Emblem B    11:15   Heikant Berlaar
10/09/2017  K. Ramsel FC        11:30   K. Lierse SK D K
(Empty row)
17/09/2017  SK Rita Berlaar A   10:00   K. RAC. Emblem B
17/09/2017  Heikant Berlaar     10:00   K. Ramsel FC 
17/09/2017  K. Bevel FC A       10:00   K. FC Pulle B
17/09/2017  K. Lierse SK D      11:45   Kessel United
```

I'm not all too familiar with PHP to figure this out entirely on my own, but I think that with some help I will be able to figure it out.

Here's a pastebin with the entire source code of the page. The list gets constructed with the `event-list.php` file.

- [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/kfmiZRSa)

As far as I'm aware, I'll probably have to store the date in a variable, then compare it with the date of the previous echoed row. And if not the same, add an empty row somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your loop where u print all rows use live below

```
$tmpdate = "";

for(loop){
    if($tmpdate != $looprecorddate){
        echo '<tr></tr>';
        $tmpdate = $looprecorddate;
    }
    // your code for print rows here 
}
```

Comment: or just post your code here so i have reply solutions in your code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/kfmiZRSa

This is a pastebin with the sourcecode.

Would be helpful if you put a little comment where you made the changes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me know if you managed to find fix my issue! Thanks in advance

Comment: I've updated my code with yours, also gave the empty row a class to distantiate it more easily. Here's the code. https://pastebin.com/aA5Q8g5a

I also gave the new class "emptyrow" a height of 14px. Which resulted in this: https://i.gyazo.com/5cb0f415be4671643c6cc5b521e02db8.png

It seems that as for now there's a <tr> echoed between every event. I was trying to get a <tr> between every block of different dates. We're getting close! :P

Comment: just debug you code to echo $tmpdate and echo $event and check echo value, also post your output jpeg link here

Comment: **Sorry for the long wait. I made a detailed picture in photoshop explaining everything.**
[Link to the picture](http://imgur.com/a/ocekG) ---- http://imgur.com/a/ocekG ------
**When I try to echo $tmpdate in the empty row, like this:**
`echo '<tr>' . $tmpdate . '</tr>'; // add blank row`

**I get the following error:**
`Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Post could not be converted to string in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\rita\wp-content\themes\football-club-child\event-list.php on line 247`

Comment: ok just replace $tmpdate = $event to $tmpdate = get_post_time( 'Y-m-d', false, $event )  and check

Comment: you just add you proper date in $tmpdate variable in IF condition

Comment: I've updated the code, I hope this is correct --- Here's a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/eea7D1Ae

But it's still printing a <tr> between every row. https://i.gyazo.com/25e9dff89bdabf12202d3f2e9e1b567d.png

Comment: what u update i can't see any changes, just replace pastebin line no. 248 and 251 with this $tmpdate = get_post_time( 'Y-m-d', false, $event );

Comment: you are welcome, if u have any freelance work for PHP, wordpress then mail me on mahipal.patel at gmail dot com